Questions about correct notations used in showing an ideal is a maximal ideal.
Background:
$$\begin{align*}
\Bbb{Z}[i] &= \{a +ib \in \Bbb Z[i] : a,b\in \Bbb{Z} \}\tag{*}\\
 \Bbb{Z}[\sqrt[n]{D}]&= \{a +b\sqrt[n]{D}: a,b, D\in \Bbb{Z} \} \tag{$\dagger$}\\
I_1 &= \{a+ib\in\mathbb{Z}[i]\ \colon\ d\mid a\wedge d\mid b,d\text{ is a prime}, a,b,d\in\mathbb{Z}\} \tag{**}\\
I_2 &= \{a+b\sqrt[n]{D}\ \colon\ d\mid a\wedge d\mid b, d\text{ is a prime,} a,b,n,d,D\in\mathbb{Z}\}\tag{$\dagger\dagger$}\\
I_3 &= \{a+bi\in\mathbb{Z}[i]\ \colon\ c\mid a, c\text{ is a prime}, a,b,c,\in\mathbb{Z}\}\tag{***}\\
I_4 &= \{a+b\sqrt[n]{D}\ \colon\ c\mid a, c\text{ is a prime}, a,b,c,n,D\in\mathbb{Z}\}\tag{$\dagger\dagger\dagger$}
\end{align*}$$
Questions:
When I try to prove an ideal/quotient ring is maxmal, I sometimes see it in the five forms above where they are the set of Gaussian integers.
For $(**)$, $(\dagger\dagger)$ above where we attached conditions to $a,b$.  Basically $(**)$ and $(\dagger\dagger)$ are both ideals.  Notationally they can be respectively denoted as either $I_1=(d)$ or $I_1=d\Bbb Z[i]$, and $I_2=(d)$ or $I_2=d\Bbb Z[\sqrt[n]{D}]$?
For $(***)$, $(\dagger\dagger\dagger)$, since we are imposing condition on $a$ only and not both $a,b$, then it would not make sense to say that $I_3=(c),$ or $I_3=c\Bbb{Z}[i]$, and $I_4=(c)$, or $I_4=c\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt[n]{D}]$?
Thank you in advance

$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[n]{D}]$ only equals the set of numbers of the form $a+b\sqrt[n]{D}$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ when $(\sqrt[n]{D})^2\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Do you not realize how confusing the statement "Basically $(2)$ and $(3)$ are both ideals" is in a setting when $2$ and $3$ are elements of the rings you are considering, as well as labels you have attached to certain equations defining sets?

The notation is an absolute mess. And note that for a ring $R$ and an element $a\in R$, the notation $R_a$ has a very specific meaning (the localization of $R$ at the multiplicative set ${a^n\mid n\geq 0}$), which is certainly not what you mean when you write $\mathbb{Z}[i]_2$... and in any case I do not understand your use of that notation. How is "$\mathbb{Z}[i]_1$", whatever that is, equal to each and every set of elements of the form $a+bi$ with $a$ and $b$ integer multiples of $d$? Who uses this notation?

@ArturoMagidin sorry about the notational confusions.  I was trying to organize my questions by lumping together sets with integers that have the same restrictions.  I was trying to make for readers to find what I was referring to with ease.  I really did not know if the way i made the notations would correspond to something already that existed in the literature.

@ArturoMagidin thank you for the edit.  I seriously did not know that my desire for trying to make my post easy to read woujld cause such confusions.  I am told many people don't bother reading background or context material preceding the main questions stated in the post.  I thought I could help expedite that process since people's time are valuable especially when the entire community is run on a volunteer basis.

Lots of problems here.

The set $\{a+b\sqrt[n]{D}\mid a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is not a ring unless $(\sqrt[n]{D})^2$ can also be expressed this way (otherwise it is not closed under multiplication), and this will generally only happen when $(\sqrt[n]{D})^2\in\mathbb{Z}$. Generally, for $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[n]{D}]$ you need elements of the form $a_0 + a_1\sqrt[n]{D} + a_2(\sqrt[n]{D})^2 + \cdots + a_{n-1}(\sqrt[n]{D})^{n-1}$. But the expression need not be unique, depending on $D$.

The set $I_1$, as written is not an ideal, because you allow $d$ to change with the element. It would contain the element $2+2i$, since $2$ is a prime that divides $2$ and $2$; and it would contain the element $3+3i$, since $3$ is a prime that divides $3$ and $3$. But it does not contain $(3+3i)-(2+2i) = 1+i$, since there is no prime $d$ that divides $1$ and $1$. So $I_1$ is not even a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. The set consists of all elements of the form $a+bi$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\gcd(a,b)>1$.

The exact same problem occurs with $I_2$, $I_3$, and $I_4$. $I_3$ is the set of all numbers of the form $a+b\sqrt[n]{D}$ with $\gcd(a,b)>1$. It's not even closed under sums, and in any case fails to be an ideal for the same reason that your description of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[n]{D}]$ fails to be a ring.

It seems reasonable that what you actually tried to describe was fixing a prime $p$, and then considering the set
$$I_1 = \{a+bi\in\mathbb{Z}[i]\mid p\mid a\wedge p\mid b, a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}.$$
That would be an ideal, but is not what you actually wrote. I assume this was the intended version for $I_1$, $I_2$, $I_3$, and $I_4$.

Even with that fix, the set $I_3$ is not an ideal. Your set contains $i$, hence also contains $i^2 = -1 = -1+0i$, which is not of the form $a+bi$ with $d\mid a$. It is a subgroup, but not an ideal.

The set $I_2$, fixed as above with $c$ fixed and outside the set description, is only an ideal if the set $\{a+b\sqrt[n]{D}\mid a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is a ring, which as noted above is not usually the case.

The set $I_4$ is not an ideal, even if the set $\{a+b\sqrt[n]{D}\mid a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is a ring and we fix $d$ outside the set description, for the same reason that $I_3$ is not an ideal.


If $R$ is a ring and $S$ is a subset of $R$, then $(S)$ is the smallest ideal of $R$ that contains $S$. When $S$ is finite, $S=\{s_1,\ldots,s_n\}$, we generally write $(s_1,\ldots,s_n)$ instead of $(\{s_1,\ldots,s_n\})$.
For $a\in R$, $(a)$ is the ideal generated by $a$; the smallest ideal that contains $a$. If $R$ is not necessarily commutative, not necessarily with unity, then
$$(a) = \left\{ na+ra + as + \sum_{j=1}^m r_jas_j\Bigm| n\in\mathbb{Z}, m\geq 0, r,s,r_j,s_j\in R\right\}.$$
If $R$ has a unity, then we can simplify this to
$$(a) = \left\{ \sum_{j=1}^m r_jas_j\Bigm| m\geq 0, r_j,s_j\in R \right\}.$$
If on the other hand $R$ is commutative but need not have a unity, then we can instead simplify to
$$(a) = \left\{ na + ra\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}, r\in R\right\}.$$
The set $aR = \{ar\mid r\in R\}$ is a right ideal of $R$. It contains $a$ if and only if there exists $r\in R$ such that $ar=a$; this happens when $R$ has a unity. Likewise, $Ra = \{ra\mid r\in R\}$ is a right ideal.
When $R$ is both commutative and with unity, then $(a) = aR = Ra$.
In the context of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, which is commutative with unity, if $c$ is any integer, then $(c) = c\mathbb{Z}[i]$.
$$\begin{align*}
(c) = c\mathbb{Z}[i] &= \{ c(a+bi)\mid a+bi\in\mathbb{Z}[i]\}\\
    & = \{r+si\in\mathbb{Z}[i]\mid r,s\in c\mathbb{Z}\}\\
&= \{ r+si\in\mathbb{Z}[i]\mid c\mid r\wedge c\mid s, r,s\in\mathbb{Z}\}.
\end{align*}$$
As your remaining sets are not ideals (sometimes not even subgroups), there is no notation for them.

if I have:  $\begin{align*}
\mathbb{Z}[i] &= { (a+bi)\mid a+bi\in\mathbb{Z}[i]}\& = {r+si\in\mathbb{Z}[i]\mid r,s\in c\mathbb{Z}}\&= { r+si\in\mathbb{Z}[i]\mid c\mid r, r,s\in\mathbb{Z}}
\end{align*}$, then $(c)\subset \mathbb{Z}[i]$?

@Seth ${r+si\in\mathbb{Z}[i]\mid r,s\in c\mathbb{Z}}\neq {r+si\in\mathbb{Z}[i]\mid c\mid r, r,s\in\mathbb{Z}}$.

@Seth No matter what $c$ is, if $c\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$, then $(c)\subset \mathbb{Z}[i]$, by definition, since $(c)$ is, in this context, "the smallest ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ that contains $c$."

I meant:  $\begin{align*}
\mathbb{Z}[i] &= { (a+bi)\mid a+bi\in\mathbb{Z}[i]}\& = {r+si\in\mathbb{Z}[i]\mid r,s\in \mathbb{Z}}\&= { r+si\in\mathbb{Z}[i]\mid c\mid r , r,s\in\mathbb{Z}}
\end{align*}$, then $(c)\subset \mathbb{Z}[i]$?  Sorry for the typo.

@Set I don't know what you think you meant, but again the second set is not equal to the third set. And again, it doesn't matter. If $c\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$, then $(c)\subseteq\mathbb{Z}[i]$. By definition.

@Seth and what does "$c\mid,$" mean?

the reason I ask about these things is because when i see showing things about Gaussian integers with one of the $r$ or $s$ having some divisibility conditions, They can't be consider as ideals, or if not, they they are subset of ideals?  Also, I see different notations for them in various algebra texts.

@Seth I really don't know what you are trying to say. "${(r+si)\mid r+si\in\mathbb{Z}[i]}$" is literally writing ${x \mid x\in A}$. Does anyone write that? The set of all Gaussian integers whose real part is divisible by a particular prime is a subgroup of the additive structure of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, but is not an ideal. Any subset of a ring is a subset of an ideal, so "they are subsets of ideals" is like asking "do they exist"?

I hope this is more clear.  Sorry, for all the confusion.  ${ r+si\in\mathbb{Z}[i]\mid c\mid r,\wedge r,s\in\mathbb{Z}}\subset \mathbb{Z}[i]  ={ (r+si)\mid r+si\in\mathbb{Z}[i]}$ and ${ r+si\in\mathbb{Z}[i]\mid c\mid r \wedge  r,s\in\mathbb{Z}}\subset c\mathbb{Z}[i]$?

@Seth. Sigh... The first part is a silly question. You are asking if a set described as ${x\in A\mid \text{...}}$ is a subset of $A$. Yes, of course it is. That's what the notation means. The second part should be clear from the explicit description of $cR$ that I wrote. $c\mathbb{Z}[i] = {c(a+bi)\mid a+bi\in \mathbb{Z}[i]}$. Do the elements of the form $c(a+bi)$ include all elements of the form $r+si$ with only $r$ a multiple of $c$? No. Since $i$ has the form $cr'+si$, but is not of the form $c(a+bi)$.

ah kk.  Thank you for clarifying that for me.

can I ask you to take a look at this post to see if I have the correct tags.  I just want to check if i got the right tags since I seem to still have a talent for creating unclear or confusingly worded posts.  You don't have to answer the question.  I just want to know if my post is clear and have the proper tags.  I think you are one of the few active mods on here who cares about these things. thank you in advance.
